# Are "arithmetic" and "rhythm" related?

Tags: etymology

The online etymology dictionary [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=arithmetic) that *arithmetic* comes from Greek *arithmos*, from PIE *re(i)- "to reason, count" and gives as cognates English "read", Old High German "rim" "number", Old Irish rim "number," and Latin ritus "religious custom".

This etymology is suspicious. First, there were no roots starting wit r- in PIE. But this can be explained adding a laryngeal before it. What is more suspicious is that Latin *ritus* is known to come from the PIE root a̯er- "fit" and cognate to the words artist, army, aristocracy, Aryan, etc.

Also the same dictionary [claims](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=row) that English word *row* comes from PIE *rei- "to scratch, tear, cut". As to me, the meanings "to tear" and "to reason, count" seem totally different.

Regarding *rhythm* the dictionary [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rhythm&allowed_in_frame=0) to come via Greek *rhythmos* from PIE *sreu- "to flow".

That said, I would like a clarification

1. Whether Greek *rhythmos* "arrangement, order, proportion" and *arithmos* "number" related.
2. Whether *arithmos* is related to artist, aristocracy etc.
3. Where to put English *row* and Russian *ряд* "r'ad" meaning "row" (Mallory and Adams put Lithuanian *rinda* "row" and Latvian *rida* "in rows" as related to *arithmos* and count the both related to ratio, artist etc).
4. Where to put the Italic *ord- "to arrange, arrangement" (> Eng. order), whether it is related to PIE *a̯rtus* "order, arrangement, juncture" (the dictionary [claims](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=order) it is of unknown origin)

Comment: "To scratch" and "to count" are actually not so distant in meaning -- making scratches on a stick or the like is a basic way of keeping count.

Comment: Too many things here. You can't just ask about every word with a rhotic in them. I'd recommend limiting it to just asking about *arithmetic*, *rhythm* and their cognates, but not *row*, *ord-* etc. Or perhaps ask if **rei-* is a PIE homophone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a language-specific etymology question.

Comment: @James Grossmann to what language it is specific? The both words exist in English and Russian for instance

Answer (score 2):

ἀριθμός and ῥυθμός both have the suffix -θμο-, otherwise they  are not related. The mainstream view, as reflected now in Beekes’s Greek etymological dictionary, is that ἀριθμός is from IE *h2rei- ‘to count’, whence also ON rim ‘account’, OHG rīm ‘row, number’, OIr. rim ‘number’, and ‘probably’, Lat. rītus ‘religious observance, rite’  < *h2rei-ti-.

ῥυθμός is from *sreu- “to stream”.

The origin of ἄριστος “best” (as in aristocracy etc.) is considered to be uncertain, but it cannot very well be connected to the aforementioned words, nor with Latin ars (as in artist).

Comment: Are you sure with the last paragraph? We have in PIE ***a̯ermntom*** fit ***a̯ermos*** fitting ***a̯eri̯os*** peer, freeman, honest 
    ***a̯rtos*** fitted 
    ***a̯ristos*** of the best sort 
    ***a̯rtis*** correct, exact ***a̯rtus*** order, arrangement

Comment: Chantraine does entertain the possibility that *aristos* is related to the *ar-* root of *ararisko* etc., and hence to Latin *ars*. I don't see any formal reason that shouldn't work.